Contradiction while solving for gain
I have been trying since long to find out the differential and common mode gain of this circuit. From my knowledge about analog design, in differential mode, the tail node goes to virtual ground, and we can look above now. From here my thought process goes like this:-

The leftmost circuit is only being used for biasing and the small signal inputs will not affect the voltages  V1, V2, V3, V4 Hence we can overall neglect this part while finding out small signal differential gain.

The transistors having 40 W/L and lowest 10 W/L would have some current flowing which does not change for small signal input, hence we can assume them as a current source only and open that node.

But this makes me at a contradiction that if there is a small signal input which increases the current then if it does not go to 40 W/L transistors, it must go down. But as lowest 10 W/L transistors have constant biasing, constant current should flow. Where does this small signal current goes then?


Please correct me and also suggest the right approach and solution to this problem.


Prabhjit Singh - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, public & legal, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in [tour] & [help].)

You are on the right track! This topology is called a folded-cascode amplifier, which leverages the complementary transistor types to yield a wider common-mode range than its telescopic counterpart. Let us analyze the differential half circuit for this architecture.

The Input Pair
The input transistor generates a small signal current of \$ g_m v_{in}/2 \$. Here, I am modeling the differential input as being taken across the two input terminals, with half of it appearing at each input. This current then sees a current divider at the output branch:
$$i_{out} = g_m \frac{v_{in}}{2}\times\frac{g_m r_o}{1+g_m r_o}\approx g_m \frac{v_{in}}{2}.$$
The Output Node
What happens at the output node then? Well, here we need to consider the channel length modulation. As you mentioned correctly, without considering \$r_o\$, no change in current is allowed, and \$v_{out}\$ is not bounded. In this case, we have the parallel combination of two output resistance terms, looking up and looking down. We can approximate this as:
$$R_{out} = R_{DN}\Vert R_{UP} \approx g_mr_o^2 \Vert \frac{g_mr_o^2}{2}.$$
This is the case because, for the cascode output resistance, we have \$ R_{cas} = r_o\lbrack 1 + (1 + (g_m + g_{m_b})r_o)\rbrack\$, assuming equal \$ r_o \$ from both of the transistors.
The Voltage Gain
We can now combine the total transconductance and the output resistance and write:
$$A_v = \frac{v_{out}}{v_{in}}=-\frac{g_m v_{in} R_{out}}{v_{in}} \approx -\frac{g_m^2r_o^2}{3}.$$
The gain is quadratic with the transistor intrinsic gain, \$g_m r_o\$, with an input pair that has a broader input common-mode range, making this topology attractive. I will finish my answer by giving you the full form of the gain equation from [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits, Behzad Razavi]:


